# Optionally publish methods based on variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

### Preface

Imagine I have a template: `template<class... Opts> class rqueue`, which can have various features selected by tags (special options structures) passed to the parameter list, e.g.

```
rqueue<trace_record, opt::fixed_size<>> trace;
rqueue<trace_record::flat, opt::fixed_size<>, opt::virtual_offset<>> info;
```

The first version (`trace`) is a record queue to be used for writing the trace records (the `opt::fixed_size` limits its size to 4096B). The second version (`info`) will get filled from the first one (by some thread, that will rewrite the records with conversion to *flat* representation), but the important thing is that `opt::virtual_offset<>` which adds these methods:

```
off_t start(); // virtual offset of oldest record
off_t stop();  // virtual offset of future record (when next gets written)
```

and various other features (`offset_to_iterator()`) based on this *virtual offset* that is always growing (with each record), which simulates virtual memory of size e.g. 4 GB (when `unsigned` used as the offset, it could be even larger with `size_t` or `unisgned long long`), where the actual buffer (of size e.g. 4096B) creates a *window* inside that virtual memory.

*[Link to my other related question - option pack helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25474036/find-untagged-template-options-parameters-args-by-position) which was specifically designed for this template.*

*(Note that thare are possibly many other features that can be independently combined, e.g. `opt::rqueue_listener` that can be used to report various events).*

### The Problem

I have managed to create that template with all the possible features, where some methods are **dummy** when the feature was not selected (e.g. `start()` is returning zero and `stop()` is same as `size()` in that case), but I would like to **hide** the methods somehow, if the feature was not selected. **Any idea?**

*(Another example would be dummy `set_listener(void*)` if the `opt::rqueue_listener` was not included - the option can be combined with any other option.)*

**EDIT:** Imagine e.g. `using off_t = conditional_t<something,the_type,void>` and `private: off_t start_()`. What I want is to:

1. Have `public: off_t start()` calling that `start_()` if `off_t` is not `void`
2. Have no method `start()` if `off_t` is void (or some condition met). Alternatively some `static_assert` if I try to call it.

### My Attempts

I was thinking about merging the class with *extenders* that would publish the functions by casting itself (`*this`) to the real class (`rqueue<...>&`) and redirecting the calls there (to private methods, where the *extender* is made a friend). I have created another `template<class... Bases> class merge` helper that could inherit any class selected while ignoring any `void` passed. It worked, but the solution is quite ugly, I don't like it.

Another possible solution that crossed my mind was to create some basic implementation (as a different template, possibly hidden in some `namespace detail`) and use a chain of template specializations that would publish the methods based on the options. Problem is that the number of combinations is growing rapidly and there could be another problem with `friend`-ing the class to have access to private methods of the record (first parameter passed to the template).

My SFINAE and `static_assert` attempts often ended with compiler errors, complaining that method specialization is not allowed in templates (or partial specializations) or the static_assert got fired when it should not. I expect there is some nice solution. Looking forward to see it :)

Comment: are opt::features always templates with one template type-parameter?

Comment: Each feature is a structure (possibly template with other parameters, but passed as a class, not as a template). I don't think that is that important. See the linked question for more details.

Comment: E.g. `fill_empty` takes two parameters - type and value: `template <class T, T V> struct fill_empty: tag::fill_empty { typedef T type; static constexpr T value = V; };`

Comment: ok, maybe I don't understand what you aim to, in short: you always implement `start()` member function, but you want it to call `virtual_offset<>::start()` when your class inherits from `virtual_offset<>`, otherwise to be inaccessible?

Comment: I mean not *inherit* but *exists within template parameter pack*

Comment: I don't want my template to have `public: off_t start()` at all if `opt::virtual_offset<...>` was not included (`off_t` can get anything in that case, my `opt::bind` will help to define it `void` if you need).

Comment: can those member functions be templated, or you are planning to make them virtual in future or smth ?

Comment: See the edit for better explanation. I don't want any `virtual`, this is `template` designed to be very `light-weight` if no special feature included (e.g. `rqueue<trace_record>` will be the basic, without additional data and methods).

Comment: So, yes, they can be templated if it will help solving it (by providing some default template args with SFINAE).

Comment: why `static_assert(!std::is_same<off_t, void>::value, "!");` in the public `start()` member function is not an option?

Comment: I think I had a problem with this, when used on basic version - the compiler triggered the assert without the need to call the method. I will check again.

Comment: Hmm, seems to work. I don't know what I was doing wrong the last time I did try something like that. I will probably accept it if you post it as an answer. Have to give it some time now.

Comment: let's wait, maybe someone has better idea. I'm curious too

Comment: Well, not having the method there at all (or some SFINAE hiding it) would be very nice, but I think I can go with this `static_assert`. I must have been working too much the last time to miss that simple solution :D

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25486033/c-class-template-specialization-without-having-to-reimplement-everything/25486107#25486107) seems to have similar answers althought the title is completely different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1

Make use of `static_assert` and the fact that template's member functions are instantiated only on demand when required by the context:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool condition = true;

template <class... Opts>
class rqueue
{
    using off_t = std::conditional_t<condition, int, void>;

public:
    off_t start()
    {
        static_assert(!std::is_same<off_t, void>::value, "!");
        return start_();
    }

private:
    off_t start_()
    {
        std::cout << "start_()" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

That said, access to `start()` when `condition` is false will trigger static assertion error:

```
error: static assertion failed: !
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a73881a8f2d856f)

#### Option 2

Use some ugly SFINAE, by making the member function a template as well:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool condition = true;

template <class... Opts>
class rqueue
{
    using off_t = std::conditional_t<condition, int, void>;

public:
    template <typename T = void>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<off_t, void>::value, off_t> start()
    {
        return start_();
    }

private:
    off_t start_()
    {
        std::cout << "start_()" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

This will trigger error:

```
error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::enable_if<false, void>'
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b75cfda2facc3485)

#### Option 3

Use some helper base class with CRTP, that implements the method conditionally:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

constexpr bool condition = true;

template <bool condition, typename CRTP>
struct start_base {};

template <typename CRTP>
struct start_base<true, CRTP>
{    
    int start()
    {
        return static_cast<CRTP*>(this)->start_();
    }
};

template <class... Opts>
class rqueue : public start_base<condition, rqueue<Opts...>>
{
    friend class start_base<condition, rqueue<Opts...>>;

private:
    int start_()
    {
        std::cout << "start_()" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
};
```

The error message on `condition = false;` is quite clear:

```
error: 'class rqueue<>' has no member named 'start'
```

[**DEMO 3**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/14793f688bf3a177)

Comment: The third version is somehow similar to my working solution with those *extenders* but looks nicer (by passing the condition instead of my `merge<conditional_t<condition,rqueue<Opts...>,void>>`) and meets the requirements exactly (by not having the methods if not needed). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The following code is what I did try after the hint from Piotr S.:
*(imagine `using namespace std` inside that header, although it is a bit different.)*

```
#include "basics.hpp"
using namespace firda;

template<class Offset = void> struct helper {
    Offset start_() const { return 0; }
};
template<> struct helper<void> {
    void start_() const {}
};

template<class Offset = void> class rqueue
  : private helper<Offset> {
public:
    Offset start() const {
        static_assert(!is_same<Offset,void>::value, "!!");
        return this->helper<Offset>::start_();
    }
};

int main() {
    rqueue<> one;
    rqueue<uint> two;
    cout << two.start();
//  one.start(); -- assert triggered
}
```

I had some problems with similar `static_assert` in my real code, but cannot remember why the compiler triggered it in basic version.... probably my mistake by calling it where it should not be. I think that having one `start_()` for internal usage (to fake it if not used) and having one `public: start()` with the assert (and making sure not to call it withitn the template) solves the problem. I will wait a while (and gladly accept different answer if it will be there).